# Have some issue with running Simple Scenario And Sensor Model 3D Simulation

Tags: matlab, 3d, simulink, scenarios

I want to run the SimpleScenarioAndSensorModel3DSimulation example on Matlab R2019b simulink. But there are 2 kind of errors which one of them is a warning and I'm not sure whether this warning leads into simulation error or not.
Here are the errors:

1. the first one which appears under the title of warning is about shadowing two libraries with the same name of "helperCoordinateTransformLib". I followed the instruction to eliminate shadowing in simulink via simulink preferences. It seems working fine but every time I re-run the matlab I face with the warning again!
2. Here is the error message:

> MATLAB System block 'SimpleScenarioAndSensorModel3DSimulation/Ego 
>       Vehicle/PlantParser/Passenger Vehicle Ray Trace Set/Simulation 3D Actor 
>       Ray Trace Read' error occurred when invoking 'setupImpl' method of 
>       'Simulation3DActorRayTraceRead'. The error was thrown from '
>        'C:\Program 
>       Files\Polyspace\R2019b\toolbox\shared\sim3d\sim3d+sim3d\Engine.p' at line 
>       0
>        'C:\Program 
>       Files\Polyspace\R2019b\toolbox\shared\sim3d\sim3d+sim3d\Engine.p' at line 
>       0
>        'C:\Program 
>        Files\Polyspace\R2019b\toolbox\shared\sim3dblks\sim3dblks\
>       Simulation3DActor.p' at line 0
>        'C:\Program 
>        Files\Polyspace\R2019b\toolbox\shared\sim3dblks\sim3dblks\
>       Simulation3DActorRayTraceRead.p' at line 0'.
>       Caused by:
>       Invalid default value for property 'engine' in class 'sim3d.Engine':
>       No method 'Start' with matching signature found for class 
>       'System.Diagnostics.Process'.

Any idea what is the problem? I appreciate your guidance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- **This bug has been solved in update 1.**
- **Install the "R2019b Update 1 v9.7.0.1216025 x64".**

Also keep in mind that your installation may require additional configuration steps.

1. The following products require a [supported compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html?sec=win64&s_cid=pi_scl_1_R2019b_win64):

Simulink Coder
Simulink Real-Time
MATLAB Coder

2. To accelerate computations with the following products, a [supported compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html?sec=win64&s_cid=pi_scl_1_R2019b_win64) is required:

SimBiology
Fixed-Point Designer

- After this installation is complete, you should continue with your configuration of the MATLAB Parallel Server as outlined in the instructions obtained from [www.mathworks.com/distconfig](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab-parallel-server/getting-started.html?s_cid=pi_dc_pi_R2019b).
- MATLAB Compiler requires a [supported compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html?sec=win64&s_cid=pi_scl_1_R2019b_win64) for creation of Excel add-ins
- MATLAB Compiler SDK requires the following:
- [.NET framework](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html?sec=win64&s_cid=pi_scl_1_R2019b_win64) for creation of .NET assemblies and deployable archives with Excel integration
- a [supported compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html?sec=win64&s_cid=pi_scl_1_R2019b_win64) for creation of COM components, C and C++ Shared libraries
- a [Java JDK](https://www.mathworks.com/support/requirements/supported-compilers.html?sec=win64&s_cid=pi_scl_1_R2019b_win64) for creation of Java packages